# Blacklist the Torah tag

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, specific-tag

As was until recently indicated on its wiki, the [torah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/torah) tag is unproductive.  Now that it is an empty tag, the wiki warning not to use it is gone.  I want to request that it be [blacklisted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19018/implement-a-tag-black-list).

---

<sub>[The original wiki](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/43915/revisions) read:</sub>

> <sub>PLEASE DO NOT USE THIS TAG. It's too vague: most questions, if not all, on this site have to do with Torah.</sub>
>
> <sub>You might mean…</sub>
>
> - <sub>[tanach](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tanach) — the Jewish Bible</sub>
> - <sub>[pentateuch-chumash](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pentateuch-chumash) — the Pentateuch (the first five books of the Bible, Genesis through Deuteronomy)</sub>
> - <sub>[torah-study](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/torah-study) — the study of religious texts (including as-yet unwritten ones)</sub>
> - <sub>[sefer-torah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sefer-torah) — the scroll on which the Pentateuch is written</sub>
> - <sub>[torah-reading](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/torah-reading) — the public reading of that scroll</sub>
> - <sub>[oral-torah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oral-torah) — religious texts (including as-yet unwritten ones) not included in the Bible</sub>
>
> <sub>…or [something else](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tags)</sub>

Comment: [similar](/q/5570)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've destroyed the tag, and I'll blacklist it, but I need a more succinct chunk of text to show to folks that attempt to use it.

Something like:

> Please don't use the 'torah' tag, as it's not very descriptive or useful for searching. Instead, use torah-reading, oral-torah, or torah-study instead. Don't worry, tags can be changed later if needed.

What are the top, say .. 3 tags someone *probably* wanted to use instead?

**Update:** Added!

[image]

Comment: The text you have looks fine. I'd recommend listing pentateuch-chumash, sefer-torah, and torah-study.

Comment: I would add Tanach. Thanks!

Comment: @IsaacMoses I would have suggested parshanut, sefer torah, and torahstudy

Comment: I'd be fine with substituting @YeZ' [tag:tanach] for [tag:pentateuch-chumash], which isn't used much. I agree with DoubleAA that [tag:parshanut-torah-comment] belongs as well. Could you put four? If so, I'd recommend: [tag:tanach], [tag:parshanut-torah-comment], [tag:sefer-torah], and [tag:torah-study].

Comment: I guess you didn't blacklist it? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/54011 uses it. From the above, I'd suggest the following text: Please don't use the 'torah' tag, as it's not very descriptive or useful for searching. Perhaps use tanach, parshanut-torah-comment, sefer-torah, or torah-study instead. Don't worry, tags can be changed later if needed.

Comment: There are now 4 questions with the tag. Can you double check the blacklist-ing?

Comment: All gone now.  This time for sure. :-)

Comment: @Shog9 Thank you! But the new text (according to its screenshot here) has "instead" twice, redundantly.

Comment: [Fixed](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=torah), @msh210

Comment: @Shog9, thanks!